# Problems with my output in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, collections

When I type the exact same answer as the elements, the output is `Right:0` and `Wrong: 10`.
The `a1`, `a2`, `a3` ... are answers I get from a text box that the user has inputted. How do I fix this?

```
private void checkUsersAnswers() {
    Collections.addAll(quizUsersAnswers, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10);
    Collections.addAll(quizAnswers, "Aphrodite", "Apollo", "Ares", "Artemis","Demeter", "Dionysus", "Hades", "Hephaestus", "Hera");
    for (int i = 0; i < quizAnswers.size(); i++) {
        if (quizUsersAnswers.contains(quizAnswers.get(i))) {
            intRight++;
        } else {
            intWrong++;
        }
    }
}

private void btnCheckUsersAnswersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    checkUsersAnswers();
    this.lblMessageRightWrong.setText("Right: "+intRight+"Wrong: "+intWrong);
}
```

I can't figure out why the output is wrong.

Comment: Please share the entire class if possible or atleast the values of a1, a2...etc

Comment: You need to create a 2D array or a Map of what a1, a2, a3, (etc) represent. Do the Questions contain multiple choice answers?

Comment: Nope, it's just one answer

Comment: static String a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10;

Comment: Not Sure how to create a 2D array as I was never taught that.

Comment: If there is same answer for two different questions, contains method may give wrong result. So I would recommend you to use equals method instead contains method while iterating or you can also implement this by using Map.